# Python iteration slow

Tags: python, optimization

I have made the following code:

```
from math import sqrt
import time


def factors(n):    
    x=(set(reduce(list.__add__, 
                ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0))))
    return sorted(x,reverse=True)


n=10**7
m=0
start_time = time.time()
for i in xrange(1,int(sqrt(n))+1):
    l=0
    x=factors(i)
    for d in xrange(i,n/i+1):
        if i==d:
            l+=i
        else:
            for b in x:
                if d%b==0:
                    l+=2*b
                    break
    m+=l
    print i

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print elapsed_time
print m
```

I think what the code does is add the greatest common divisor of i and d for all id≤n

Due to the "print i", I have realized that when i is small the second loop is slow. Why is this?, and how do I optimize?

I see that the iteration over d will be larger, but shouldn't it essentially just be iterating over all the values, whereas for the larger i, the third loop should take a longer time because of the greater size of x.

Answer (score 0):

Could the second loop be slower for small values of i just because the xrange "spans" a larger amount of values for small i?

I mean, in the second loop declaration we have:

for d in xrange(i,n/i+1):

And the maximum value of the xrange (this is, n/i+1) is larger for small i (the quotient n/i is maximum at i=1, then it decreases

Answer (score 0):

Your ideas about how long each loop should take to run a single time relative to one another are accurate, but the differences in them is minimal.

Your assumptions about how many times each loop is running are off by several orders of magnitude.

Loop i is executing ~3000 times.  The total number of loop executions called per i varies but on average drops at an high rate.  At the start, the d loop is getting called ~ 10,000,000 per i and then it drops off very quickly:

The total number of loops you run for i[0:215]  is greater than i[215:3161]

```
i               d_loops         b_loops         running_mean            avg_last_10_loops
1               10000001        1               10000001.0              10000001.0
2               5000001         2               10000001.5              10000001.5
3               3333334         2               8888890.33333           8888890.33333
4               2500001         3               8541668.5               8541668.5
5               2000001         2               7633335.2               7633335.2
6               1666667         4               7472224.0               7472224.0
7               1428572         2               6812926.85714           6812926.85714
8               1250001         4               6586311.5               6586311.5
9               1111112         3               6224869.77778           6224869.77778
10              1000001         4               6002383.2               6002383.2
99              101011          6               1653200.16162           637628.2
199             50252           2               1035550.34171           324231.5
299             33445           4               779296.658863           203848.2
399             25063           8               634848.313283           192922.4
499             20041           2               540089.59519            149790.4
599             16695           2               472549.51586            114461.6
699             14307           4               421785.891273           103772.2
799             12516           4               382086.017522           100739.8
899             11124           4               349883.460512           80518.2
999             10011           8               323351.570571           80530.4
1099            9100            4               300961.77434            67638.0
1199            8341            4               281811.0                61978.2
1299            7699            4               265260.015396           65681.9
1399            7148            2               250684.336669           54528.4
1499            6672            2               237863.799199           49524.2
1599            6254            8               226449.282051           56452.4
1699            5886            2               216141.950559           47237.4
1799            5559            4               206859.735964           43485.8
1899            5266            6               198471.47762            49653.2
1999            5003            2               190769.076538           38112.8
2099            4765            2               183702.581706           34396.0
2199            4548            4               177231.36653            36467.0
2299            4350            6               171250.213136           35741.6
2399            4169            2               165683.010838           34256.8
2499            4002            12              160541.983994           39293.2
2599            3848            4               155707.039246           35478.6
2699            3706            2               151193.218229           27470.6
2799            3573            6               146973.628796           30790.8
2899            3450            4               143019.365643           29714.8
2999            3335            2               139271.870957           28064.8
3099            3227            4               135755.08777            27799.4
3153            3172            4               133946.542341           33037.6
3154            3171            8               133912.116677           30484.8
3155            3170            4               133873.691284           29208.8
3156            3169            12              133843.321926           29196.8
3157            3168            8               133808.95407            30460.0
3158            3167            4               133770.594047           29820.6
3159            3166            12              133740.27477            32349.4
3160            3165            16              133713.977215           25983.4
3161            3164            4               133675.679848           25979.4
3162            3163            16              133649.409235           27867.2
```